# Trouble with TensorFlow and MNIST recognition

Tags: tensorflow

Beforehand, I thank you for analyzing my post and helping out. I've recently gotten interested in ML with Tensorflow,

but I've encountered a problem with my code. I'm reading a book called Learning TensorFlow, and I've written out the whole thing

from the first example. They are analyzing MNIST images, and I've also added my own comments with my perspective on how things work

in the code. When I run the code, however, I get an error. Here's my code, and the error.

```
#Import tensorflow under the name of ts

import tensorflow as tf

#Import MNIST tutorial data from tensorflow

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data



#Declare constants

#Data path

DATA_DIR = 'C:/tmp/data'

#Number of steps

NUM_STEPS = 1000

#Number of examples per step

MINIBATCH_SIZE = 100





#When we read the data-set it saves it locally under our data path, or under c:/tmp/data

data = input_data.read_data_sets(DATA_DIR, one_hot = True)

#Our placeholder X is the image. Placeholders are supplied when running the computation graph

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

#Create a variable representing the weights. Variables are manipulated by the computation graph

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))



y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

y_pred = tf.matmul(x, W)



cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(

        logits=y_pred, labels=y_true))



gd_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)



correct_mask = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pred, 1), tf.argmax(y_true, 1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_mask, tf.float32))



with tf.Session() as sess:

    #Initialize global variables

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())



    for _ in range(NUM_STEPS):

        batch_xs, batch_ys = data.train.next_batch(MINIBATCH_SIZE)

        sess.run(gd_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_true: batch_ys})



    ans = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: data.test.images,

                                        y_true: data.test.labels})



print("Accuracy: {:.4}%".format(ans*100))
```

Now here's the error.

```
    runfile('C:/Users/user/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/user/.spyder-py3')

Extracting C:/tmp/data\train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz

Extracting C:/tmp/data\train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz

Extracting C:/tmp/data\t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz

Extracting C:/tmp/data\t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz

Traceback (most recent call last):



  File "<ipython-input-11-bf503334b166>", line 1, in <module>

    runfile('C:/Users/user/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/CwWJc/.spyder-py3')



  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile

    execfile(filename, namespace)



  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile

    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)



  File "C:/Users/user/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 38, in <module>

    sess.run(gd_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_true: batch_ys})



  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 950, in run

    run_metadata_ptr)



  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1149, in _run

    str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))



ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100, 10) for Tensor 
    'Placeholder_15:0', which has shape '(?, 784)'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Sorry if I'm making a stupid mistake. I find that I often do, though. Thanks in advance! Also, sorry for garbage formatting. :)

Comment: it looks like you are not able to understand the error. You should get better help at wherever you got the code from. Please read the book carefully, they would have probably mentioned it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Hahaha! I got y_true mixed up. Sorry for the hassle everyone.